# short hand for using str_detect and & in filter

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to get the short hand for using `str_detect` and `&` to `filter` a dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(type = c("age", "age and sex", "sex"))
#          type
# 1         age
# 2 age and sex
# 3         sex
```

I want to shorten this pipe

```
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(type, "age") & str_detect(type, "sex"))
#          type
# 1 age and sex
```

So I'd like to pipe the filter to `map` over `pattern <- c("age", "sex")` and maybe use `reduce` somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regex to specify zero or more characters (`*`) following the 'age'  succeeded by 'sex'. The `\\b` is to specify word boundary so that it won't match 'adage' etc.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   filter(str_detect(type, '\\bage\\b.*\\bsex'))
```

---

Or use `map/reduce`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
   filter(map(c('age', 'sex'), ~ str_detect(type, .x)) %>% reduce(`&`))
```

Comment: thanks, I like that! Would you know a short hand to pass a vector `pattern <- c("age", "sex")` to filter with `&`?

Comment: @user63230 YOu can use `str_c(pattern, collapse = " and ")` and then do a `==`